# The value 0 is not shown in a cell. Why?

Tags: excel

I enter the formula:

```
=IF(OR(A3<>"";B3<>"";C3<>"";D3<>"";E3<>"";F3<>"";L3<>"";R3<>"";W3<>"";AB3<>"");ROW();0)
```

into a cell. Strangely the cell does not display the value 0, it displays nothing. However if I change the formula ti:

```
=IF(OR(A3<>"";B3<>"";C3<>"";D3<>"";E3<>"";F3<>"";L3<>"";R3<>"";W3<>"";AB3<>"");ROW();"0")
```

it displays a 0. Why doesn't it display a zero in the first case? I've checked the cell formating and it's "General". I can't think of what other could be causing this.

Comment: Under `options>Advanced>Display options for the worksheet` there is a check box for `show a zero in cells that have zero value` is that checked for the sheet your working in?

Comment: @gtwebb - your comment is worth posting as answer.

Comment: In combination with the answers already given a text 0 is different than a 0 and the display 0's if for values, not text.

Comment: You may find it simpler to use COUNTA function like this `=IF(COUNTA(A3;B3;C3;D3;E3;F3;L3;R3;W3;AB3);ROW();0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under options>Advanced>Display options for the worksheet there is a check box for `show a zero in cells that have zero value`.  Make sure this is checked for your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is a bit wrong. It should be this way:

```
=IF(OR(A3<>"",B3<>"",C3<>"",D3<>"",E3<>"",F3<>"",L3<>"",R3<>"",W3<>"",AB3<>""),ROW(),0)
```

Replace (;)-semi-colon with (,)-comma. That should return (0) *int* value.

On the otherhand:

```
=IF(OR(A3<>"",B3<>"",C3<>"",D3<>"",E3<>"",F3<>"",L3<>"",R3<>"",W3<>"",AB3<>""),ROW(),"0")
```

will return a (0) *string* value.

Comment: The formula is not wrong. Some versions of excel (French for instance) use `;` instead of `,` in formulae.